# Merging Nodes on Path calculating a (compound) Properties of the relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

(Using Neo4j 3.x and the neo4j.v1 Python driver)

I have a track consisting of a linked list of nodes each one representing a (lon, lat) pair of coordinates.

`(A)-[:NEXT]->(B)-[:NEXT]->(C)   etc.
    with properties lon, lat on each node`

**Question 1**

The direct distance between the coordinates of two neighboring nodes, e.g. (0,0) and (1,1), could be added as a "distance" property of the relationship -[:NEXT {distance: 1.41421}]-> between the two neighboring nodes. How could you do that given that I have thousands of nodes like this?

[image: From the coordinates of A and B, a distance can be calculated and added as a property to the relationship]

**Question 2**

Whole segments of this linked list of nodes could be replaced by a single -[:NEXT]-> relationship with the "distance" property as the sum of all the distances between adjacent nodes of the original list. How could this be done efficiently for, again, thousands or more nodes?

`(A)-[:NEXT {distance: 1}]->(B)-...->(D)-[:NEXT {distance: 1}]->(E)
    (A)-[:NEXT {distance: 4}}->(E)`

[image: The distance between individual nodes in the first graph is added and the result assigned to the distance property in graph two, with all the intermediate nodes removed]

Thank you for your guidance and hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part1 : You're using lat/lon, in neo4j 3.0 there is native support for point and distance, make sure to use `latitude` and `longitude` property keys. You can then set this property on the relationship with the following :

```
MATCH (start:YourNodeLabel)-[r:NEXT]->(end)
SET r.distance = distance(point(start), point(end)) / 1000
```

Part 2 : If you know the start and end node of the path, you can then create this next relationship by reducing the distance properties of the relationships :

```
MATCH (start:YourNodeLabel {name:"A"}), (end:YourNodeLabel {name:"E"})
MATCH (start)-[r:NEXT*]->(end)
CREATE (start)-[newrel:NEXT]->(end)
SET newrel.distance = reduce(d=0.0, x IN r | d + x.distance)
```

Be careful however with this, taking into account that there could be more than one `path` from `start` to `end`, in that case for eg if you want to find the shortest distance from start to end, you will need to calculate the total distance and take the lowest one :

```
MATCH (start:YourNodeLabel {name:"A"}), (end:YourNodeLabel {name:"E"})
MATCH p=(start)-[:NEXT*]->(end)
WITH p, start ,end, reduce(d=0.0, x IN rels(p) | d + x.distance) as totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
LIMIT 1
CREATE (start)-[newRel:NEXT]->(end)
SET newRel.distance = totalDistance
```

If you don't have the distance properties on the relationships, you can also calculate the geo distance on the fly in the reduce functions :

```
MATCH (start:YourNodeLabel {name:"A"}), (end:YourNodeLabel {name:"E"})
MATCH p=(start)-[:NEXT*]->(end)
WITH p, start, end, 
reduce(d=0.0, x IN range(1, size(nodes(p))-1) | d + distance(point(nodes(p)[x-1]), point(nodes(p)[x])) / 1000) as distance
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 1
CREATE (start)-[newRel:NEXT]->(end)
SET newRel.distance = distance
```

As a general advise, I wouldn't use the same relationship type name for the relationship used as a shortcut, maybe `CONNECT_TO` or `REACH_POINT` can be more suited in order to not to interfer with the `NEXT` relationships in other queries.

Comment: Brilliant, this is very helpful. Thank you so much!
Side Question: if I had some weird metrics and, say, space-time coordinates, how would you implement your distance calculation? As a stored procedure? I am glad that Neo4j 3.x has native support for geodistance, but you never know...

Comment: Yeah if you can do a bit of java, i would go with procedures